# How to set <a> href automatically to another div onclick function href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a div like this:

```
<div onclick="location.href='';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="item">   
        <a href="example" class="btn">Buy</a>                
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to automatically assign `href` of `<a>` which is set to `example` to `href` of onclick function:

`<div onclick="location.href='';" style="cursor: pointer;">`

So how to do this?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there only one child element anchor tag inside the div ?

Comment: @AmitVerma No this was just for an example, but I can set id or class name

Comment: You mean remove the onclick from the div and transfer it's location to the a href?

Comment: @Kinglish I mean put the href value of `<a>` tag and put it onclick href. For example in this example, onclick div would be: `<div onclick="location.href=''example;" style="cursor: pointer;">`

Comment: Are you generating this HTML? If so, do you not have access to that data already?

Comment: @cerealikaeme On which user action do you want to do this?

Comment: @Charlie There is no user action here. Just anything that appears on href link value woudl be placed at `<div onclick="location.href='';" style="cursor: pointer;">` as well.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear on your use case. Maybe add an attempt at the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @cerealikaeme Should this happen at the start of the script? If so, why don't you just type the same address in both the places?

Comment: @Charlie This is just an example, my div contains many child elements but I need to define the `<a href='LINK'` at the onlick href automatically

Comment: Do you already know how to get the two elements in question?

Comment: @Ace I'm not familliar with Javascript so much

Comment: That's fine, but we need more context on your situation. Are you generating this HTML yourself? Do you want this action to happen when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript will be like this

```
 function setLocation(divObj) {
            var anchorTag = divObj.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

            console.log(anchorTag);

            window.location.href = anchorTag.href;
        }
```

and HTML will be

```
<div onclick="setLocation(this);" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="example" class="btn">Buy</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an event listener to the div and modifying the a tag from the event.

Note that `ev.target` actually points to the `<a>` tag itself, rather than the `<div>`.

```html
<div id="buy-div" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="item">   
        <a class="btn" href="example">Buy</a>                
    </div>  
</div>
```

```js
const buyDivEl = document.getElementById('buy-div');
buyDivEl.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    ev.target.href = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class for any div that should inherit the href of the anchor link inside it and loop through them, creating the listener and grabbing the href.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.inheritor').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      window.location.href = e.target.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.inheritor {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class='inheritor'>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="example" class="btn">Buy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP is trying to set the `href` of the `a` not navigate the page.

Comment: Can you tell me what the difference is? `onclick='location.href=""'` vs `element.addEventListener('click'...` They are both event listeners. The fact that this code references the href at the time of the click is actually better since the href might change.

Comment: The issue is `window.location.href = ...`. You are navigating the page, the OP only wants to set an  attribute on the `a` tag. Those are very different things.

Comment: the purpose of window.location.href is to navigate the page. Sorry, I am only seeing a semantic difference, not a functional one. OP said they want the href value applied to the div onclick -- not the other way around.

Comment: The question and comments expressed wanting to set an attribute on a tag, not to navigate the page as you are doing. Nevertheless, if they found your answer useful I guess this is what they were trying to achieve. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, you may want to do something like this:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivId");

const prevOnClickAttr =  myDiv.getAttribute("onclick")
// formatting in order to insert the anchors attribute inside the string value more easly
.split("=")[0]+"='";

console.log("previous onclick: ", myDiv.getAttribute("onclick"));

const onClickToAdd = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href")
// closing the string value here
+"';";

myDiv.setAttribute( "onclick", prevOnClickAttr + onClickToAdd );

console.log("new onclick div's attribute: ",myDiv.getAttribute("onclick"));
```

```html
<div id="myDivId" onclick="location.href='';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="item">   
        <a href="#myDivId" class="btn">Buy</a>                
    </div>  
</div>
```

where of course you may prefer to wrap the javascript code into a function, just in case you want to reuse it many times